# How to avoid url conflict when defining menu items, and make sure path without wildcards will be used in favor of path with %?

Tags: hooks, routes

In `hook_menu`, I have

```
$path = "events"

$items[$path] = array(
  'title' => t('Events'),
  'page callback' => 'my_events_page',
  'access arguments' => array('view my events'),
  'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  'file' => 'my_events.pages.inc',
);

$items[$path . '/past'] = array(
  'title' => t('Past events'),
  'page callback' => 'my_events_past_page',
  'access arguments' => array('view my events'),
  'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  'file' => 'my_events.pages.inc',
);

$items[$path . '/%'] = array(
  'title' => t('Events'),
  'page callback' => 'my_events_page',
  'page arguments' => array($depth),
  'access arguments' => array('view my events'),
  'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  'file' => 'my_events.pages.inc',
);
```

They were working, but not now.

If I change `$items['events/past']` to `$items['events/past1']`, it works.

Does it mean I have path conflict? If so, how can I resolve it?

Rows in my `{menu_router}` table are as follows:

```
path: events
page_callback: views_page (but I set it to xxx_events_page in hook_menu)
fit: 1
include_file: empty (should not be empty)
--
path: events/%
page_callback: xxx_events_page (good)
fit: 2
include_file: a file path is there
--
path: events/past
page_callback: views_page (but I set it to xxx_events_past_page in hook_menu)
fit: 3
include_file: empty (should not be empty)
```

If I update the `page_callback` and `include_file` it works. If I clear the cache, everything set back to default.

Comment: I took liberty to re-format your post and make it a consistent whole. Of course feel free to edit it again if you feel I missed something.

Comment: Do you have any module that might define `events` path? See `{menu_links}` table, `router_path` and `module` columns.

Comment: Solved. The issue is I defined the same path in views. I see a page_callback "views_page" in menu_router table, but I never understand what it means. (It gives me hint about view, but I never try to understand it.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Drupal 7:

Order matters only a bit - [`menu_router_build()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_router_build/7) saves all path into the `{menu_router}` table just the way they are set. But there are no guarantees database will return elements in that order. Logic to decide which menu item should be executed is in [`menu_get_item()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_get_item/7).

Actual query is:

```
$router_item = db_query_range('SELECT * FROM {menu_router} WHERE path IN (:ancestors) ORDER BY fit DESC', 0, 1, array(':ancestors' => $ancestors))->fetchAssoc();
```

As you can see, fitting elements are ordered by `fit` column, most specific first.

As you can see in actual [`_menu_router_build()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/_menu_router_build/7), `$fit` gets initially set to 0 for each menu item:

```
foreach ($callbacks as $path => $item) {
  $load_functions = array();
  $to_arg_functions = array();
  $fit = 0;
```

It means it shouldn't be possible for the order of menu elements in `hook_menu()` to affect order of routing. Actual code is a bit complicated to understand, but elements specific should have higher `fit` than elements with '%' in them. As the comment in code says: *// If there is no %, it fits maximally.*

Answer (score 0):

I use this code bellow in a custom module "mymodule" with drupal 7 and everthing work well. What version of Drupal do you use ?

```
 <?php

    function mymodule_menu() {
        $path = "events";

        $items[$path] = array(
            'title' => t('Events'),
            'page callback' => 'my_events_page',
            'access arguments' => array('access content'),
            'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
            //'file' => 'my_events.pages.inc',
        );

        $items[$path . '/%'] = array(
            'title' => t('Events'),
            'page callback' => 'my_events_page',
            'page arguments' => array($depth),
            'access arguments' => array('access content'),
            'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
            //'file' => 'my_events.pages.inc',
        );


        $items[$path . '/past'] = array(
            'title' => t('Past events'),
            'page callback' => 'my_events_past_page',
            'access arguments' => array('access content'),
            'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
            //'file' => 'my_events.pages.inc',
        );

        return $items;
    }

    function my_events_page(){
        print "hello";
    }

    function my_events_past_page(){
        print "past";
    }

    ?>
```